# Replicating ImageMagicks 'Badge using Lighting Effects' using PIL

Tags: python, imagemagick, thumbnails, python-imaging-library

ImageMagick has a cool technique of 'wrapping' an image onto a greyscale 'mask'. It creates a cool button effect for thumbnails. I would like assistance in converting a method i have seen done with ImageMagick to PIL.
I don't want to use any wrappers to ImageMagick. I need to recreate this in PIL. I dont want to use a traditional mask. Does PIL have sufficient capability to reproduce this effect?

**Original in ImageMagick:**
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#badge_lighting

I'm pretty familiar with basic ImageMagick and PIL like scaling and line drawing, but this example is on the *complex* side. Are there any PIL experts capable of assisting?

**The ImageMagick source**

```
# merge "mask 'n' paint" images with a gray image,
# to create a "lighting mask"
convert -size 90x90 xc:gray50 -alpha set \
      badge_mask.png -compose DstIn -composite \
      badge_shading.png -compose Over -composite \
      badge_lighting.png

# Apply the single "lighting mask"
convert thumbnail.gif -alpha set -gravity center -extent 90x90 \
      badge_lighting.png \
      \( -clone 0,1 -alpha Opaque -compose Hardlight -composite \) \
      -delete 0 -compose In -composite \
      badge_final.png
```

input RGB imageA (likely jpg)

input RGBA imageB (png file - greyscale or channels will be converted to)

output RGBA resultimage (png file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what imagemagick does, but the result is very similar.
I transformed badge template pixel values using function (`transparent_when_gray`) to create alpha mask which is totally transparent for 127 (which is "base" color of the badge template) and more opaque as the value gets bigger or smaller.
Then I use this alpha-mask to composite the badge template and source image.

```
import Image, ImageChops, ImageOps

def transparent_when_gray(x):
    return 255 if x == 127 else 255 - 2 * abs(127 - x)

def mk_badge(img, template):
    templ = template.convert('RGBA')
    r, g, b, alpha = templ.split()
    gray = ImageOps.grayscale(Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b)))
    amask = gray.point(transparent_when_gray)

    res = ImageChops.composite(img, templ, amask)
    res.putalpha(alpha)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image    = Image.open('thumbnail.gif')
    template = Image.open('badge_lighting.png')

    image_cropped = ImageOps.fit(image, template.size)

    badge = mk_badge(image_cropped, template)
    badge.save('badge.png')
```